# How fix 'The given object is not an Optimizer instance' when using Tensorflow-2.0 tf.optimizers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 with the standard DNNClassifier estimator. It seems that the Optimizers in tf.optimizers are not instances of the Optimizer expected by the classifier.

I have already used tf.optimizers and the new keras implementation at tf.keras.optimizers and get the same error.
Even using the estimator call as a lambda function still returns the same message.

```py
lr = tf.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=0.1,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.96)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier([20, 45, 15],
                                        feature_columns,
                                        n_classes=df.target.nunique(),
                                        optimizer=optimizer)

classifier.train(input_fn=lambda: df_to_dataset(
    train, batch_size=batch_size), steps=10000)
```

Everytime I execute i get the same message, doesn't matter which optimizer I choose:

`The given object is not an Optimizer instance. Given: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam object at 0x7f7f186dada0>`

Comment: Use `tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()` instead of `tf.optimizers.Adam()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Vlad but that works up to a point. There's a problem that comes later with a built in function ```/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in _call_if_callable(self, param)
   1220   def _call_if_callable(self, param):
   1221     """Call the function if param is callable."""
-> 1222     return param() if callable(param) else param

TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'```

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere in your code. I need to see full traceback to help you.

Comment: @Vlad, you can submit you answer for me to accept it. I ended up building my optimizers with compat v1 and model whith v2. That way we can get across this issue. As per my answer below, this is a known issue for the next release.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer()` instead of `tf.optimizers.Adam()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for whomever finds this:

This issue is a blocker for the future release of Tensorflow 2.0.
I found a similar issue today on the github repository:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20812

As of today, there's no workaround but to use tailor made estimators. (I'm not sure if even that works)

Edit: I found a workaround thanks to @Vlad. He suggested to use compat to build the estimator, so I did.
Here is how the code ended up looking:

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(
    learning_rate=tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
        global_step=0,
        learning_rate=0.1,
        decay_steps=10000,
        decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using tensorflow.python.keras api for model and layers and keras.optimizers for SGD. They are two different keras versions of tensorflow and pure keras. They could not work together. You have to change everything to one version.

After this, my code work well :P

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried to use both tensorflow implementation of optimizers and tf.keras optimizers, they are not working for Estimators so far.